# Finding a particular angle from a triangle

Tags: geometry

[image]

The way I have seen a solution is very lengthy  to find the value  of x. Is there any easy way to get the value of x? I have tried   different formula and didn't get any shortcut  solution.

Comment: Hint: Drop the altitude AE. Use trigonometric ratios for 45 and 60 degree angles to determine AE, DE and CE. tan(x)=AE/EC.

Comment: I have  used the $\sin$ rule but that takes time

Comment: Just realized something.. with the altitude AE, you can simply conclude - AE=BE=2DE. Hence DE=CE=1. Hence x=60 degrees. It was trivial.

Comment: @DeepakGupta: No, $BE\not=2DE$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Place point $E$ on $\overline{AD}$ such that $\angle CED = 60^{\circ}$.

Now, by the Law of Sines in $\triangle ABD$,

$$\frac{\sin 15^{\circ}}{1}=\frac{\sin 45^{\circ}}{\overline{AD}}$$

$$\therefore \overline{AD} = 1 + \sqrt{3}$$

Since $\triangle CDE$ is equilateral, $\overline{DE} = 2$.

$$\therefore \overline{AE} = \overline{AD} - \overline{DE} = (1 + \sqrt{3}) - 2 = \sqrt{3} - 1$$

Now notice:

$$\frac{\overline{AE}}{\overline{EC}} = \frac{\overline{BD}}{\overline{DA}}$$

Because:

$$\frac{\sqrt{3} - 1}{2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3} + 1}$$

Since that's true, and since $\angle BDA = \angle AEC = 120^{\circ}$, $\therefore \triangle ABD \sim \triangle CAE$.

The rest falls into place.

$\angle CAE = \angle ABD = 45^{\circ}$, so $\angle CAB = 15^{\circ} + 45^{\circ} = 60^{\circ}$, meaning $\angle ACB = \angle x = \color{red}{75^{\circ}}$.